# Sybase monitoring updates LastUpdateDate null

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I want to monitor a table's changes with master..**monOpenObjectActivity** monitoring table, but last update/insert/delete dates are NULL all the time.

After update/insert/delete, the corresponding monOpenObjectActivity columns are not set:

- **LastUpdateDate**, **LastInsertDate** and **LastDeleteDate** are NULL
- **Updates**, **Inserts** and **Deletes** are 0
  [image]
- but **RowsInserted**, **RowsDeleted** and **RowsUpdated** are counting correctly
  [image]

The configuration parameters **"enable monitoring"**, **"per object statistics active"**, and **"object lockwait timing"** are enabled.
My configs for monitoring tables are the following:
[image]

***Notes:***

- *I want to mention that I did use the monOpenObjectActivity table with other tables, and had no problem. For any other table, the timestamps are registered in monOpenObjectActivity.*
- *sybase version: ASE 16.0 SP02*

Comment: I would open a case with SAP you could be hitting a bug. You don't mention which patch on SP02 you're using but I would hope its not the base SP02 build as that has serious security vulnerabilities which have been patched since (SP02 PL09 HF1 is the latest which fixes these on SP02).

Comment: @RichCampbell that's what I get when I execute sp_version: 16.0 SP02 PL04/EBF 26121

Comment: @RichCampbell for **select @@version** -> *Adaptive Server Enterprise/16.0 SP02 PL04/EBF 26121 SMP/P/X64/Windows Server/ase160sp02pl04x/0/64-bit/FBO/Fri Jun 10 16:16:25 2016*

Comment: Yes thats a lower patch version which has some security vulnerabilities you may want to plan to patch that.